# Regular Expression for nnn nn

Tags: regex

I have a requirement that need to write a regular expression to accept only `### ##` format. Three numbers, a single space and two more numbers.

I've tried: `\d{3}\s?\d{2}$`

Can someone help

Comment: This is a pretty easy regex, you should try it before asking for help. If you are unable to do it, post what you got and we will help you from there.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: i tried this  new Regex(@"\d{3}\s?\d{2}$");

Comment: And does it work? Because it looks right to me. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Well if it will be strictly that, you can use this. keep it simple and stupid. regexr.com/4t6er

Comment: Honestly, this is an incredibly easy regex. Your regex should match what you're trying to match, absent of any other specifications. That said, I'd wager you want to get rid of the `?` after the `\s` if the format is always `### ##` and not `#####`

Comment: You missed `^` at the start and if the space is not optional remove `?` after `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do it I guess. This is one of them:

```
^[\d]{3}[\s]{1}[\d]{2}$
```

Comment: There are many ways to do what he wants to do, including what he already had, which is why we need to find out what the problem is with that.

Comment: Why do you put a simple `\d` or `\s` in a character class? `{1}` is useless.

Comment: No particular reason. I just tried to do it in a way that it was explicit, not ambiguous and easy to read as each group is defined in a consistent way (char class in group + quantifier with initial and end of line anchors). How your approach would be?